# How to get Environment Variable in csproj file?

Tags: .net, environment-variables, appsettings

I want to get **the environment variable** in csproj, because there I have a condition which exclude appsettings from publish.

[image]
[image]

I want this because, my appsettings didn't depends to Solution Configuration, them depends only from environment variables.

Instead of '$(Configuration)' != Debug' I want something like 'envVariable != Development' etc.

Or is it another method to exclude those files regarding to env variables?

in C# is this method: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ").`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

So I ran into this same problem today and got it working rather easily. This was one of the first relevant results on google when I searched for this so thought I'd share.

Actually the `$()` operator is used to resolve any variable within the .csproj but it's also seeded with environment variables already when MSBuild is triggered. So in your case you could do `$(envVariable)` or `$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)`.

They're brought in like any other `.csproj` variable.