# How to refer to developer-specific variables in the project file?

Tags: c#, environment-variables, csproj

I'm working with a specific solution template. This template makes use of a powershell script, called through the .csproj project file, for building the application. I would like to use an environment variable, or something of the sort, which will not be synchronized to the git repository. This is because of some settings which have to differ in the powershell script between developers.

Most info I find out there is about using environment variables in your .cs files, but that is not where I'm trying to use them here. Furthermore I have come across several ways of using local variables, and it's difficult for me to tell what to use. There's `launchSettings.json`, `Settings.settings`, and I believe another one I'm now forgetting. `launchSettings.json` also has several options within itself, `commandLineArgs` and `Environment variables`.

I know how to create a local .txt file and read that out with the powershell script, but it seems to me like there should be a more built-in "proper" way of going about this.

This is the relevant line in the .csproj file:

```xml
<Exec Command="PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File installScript.ps1 -someArguments myArguments/>
```

---

Further context:
From what I've been able to find myself, and as linked below, using $(MyVariable) in .csproj should give the value of the desired env variable? But if so I have been unable to get that to work.

I have tried adding env variables through VS '22 "Debug > Project Debug Properties > Environment Variables", yielding the below `launchSettings.json`:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "ProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "MyVariable": "MyValue"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then trying:

```xml
<Exec Command="PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File installScript.ps1 -MyArgument &quot;$(MyVariable)&quot;/>
```

Results in an empty field: [image: powershell output]

```txt
Executing deployment script...
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File installScript.ps1 **** -MyArgument ""
```

Comment: So if I got you right, you want to to pass a variable to your PS-script from your project-file, right?

Comment: Is it enough for you to read an environment variable? This question answers that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48618357/21398414 Or do you have additional requirements apart from no version control?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I want to pass a local variable to my PS-script, be it directly or with a detour through the project-file.

Comment: @JineappleAra I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have an env variable defined in my launchSettings.json 
{"profiles":{
"proj.name"{
"commandName": "Project",
"environmentVariables": {
"MyVariable": "MyValue"
}}}}, but when I use <Exec Command="ps... -someArgument $(MyVariable)"/> it yields a blank.

Comment: your problem is, that as soon as you *compile* your project into as assembly, the csproj-file is effectivly pointless. Or in other words: the csproj-file contains instrctions about how to *build* your project, not about *running* it.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain the powershell script is part of the deployment. I have made an edit to hopefully explain things further. Forgive the confusion.

Comment: `launchSettings.json` contain settings (launch profiles) to launch your app locally.

Comment: _"but it seems to me like there should be a more built-in "proper" way of going about thi"_ - without having full overview sounds like you are trying to do something which is neither build-in or "proper". If you want environment variables to be used - you need to declare one one the target machines in this case.

Comment: Pretty good question, but one minor detail:    It's preferable etiquette to list text-based errors in actual text format in your question rather than as an image.  You can still redact information with ***'s or something.

Comment: @GuruStron I'm running something locally for testing. Because of how it's set up I need to be able to specify some sort of local target for deploying my test code. This target can differ between machines. This specified target is needed when running the deployment powershell script. Given I'm not the only one working on this project, I want to use some sort of local variable which won't be synched to git. I don't know what the proper word or term to use is, I have assumed envVar but that's just because it looks like what I need.

Comment: @Wyck thanks for the notice, I've edited my question to include both.

Comment: @tbeest again - you can use environment variables but they should be set up on your machine, not in `launchSettings.json`. Or you can place needed info in some ignored file. It is up to you.

Comment: @GuruStron yet these are settings I might want to change on a project-by-project basis. Do forgive my ignorance, but what's the point of having environment variables within VS if those aren't supposed to be used? From what I can find that's exactly what they're for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295228/is-launchsettings-json-in-a-dotnet-core-project-used-in-production

Comment: @tbeest _"but what's the point of having environment variables within VS"_ - I never said it should not be used. As I wrote previously - they are used to RUN the application, what you want to do happens on BUILD. You can read "manually" the file (though it is a question what profile, since there usually are several). Also in my experience `launchSettings.json` usually are committed to the repo hence are synchronized in git.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the secrets manager: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows

In Visual Studio, you can right-click a project to manage user secrets, which override appsettings(.development).json

Or you can use the `dotnet` cli: `dotnet user-secrets set "Movies:ServiceApiKey" "12345"`

As the name implies, it's intended for secrets that shouldn't be committed to version control, but I think it works fine as well for this. You can also set a key in appsettings.json, e.g. `"ServiceApiKey": "SetInSecretsJson"` to remind the developer where it's stored.

You can then access the variable from PowerShell like this:

`(dotnet user-secrets list | Select-String 'Movies:ServiceApiKey = (.*)').Matches[0].Groups[1].Value`

Combine this with calling your PowerShell script and I believe this should achieve your goal.